# Is there any way to change wallpaper according to specific clock time?

Tags: 11.04, themes, desktop-background, time

Finding it quite hard to Google this. Between say 9 am and 6pm I want a certain wallpaper to be displayed, and between 6 pm to 12 am I want a different one. So I want it time-specific.

Any way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: never google for applications! Use the Ubuntu Software Center. It's a lot easier to find what you want that way: search for "wallpaper" and you would have found both desktop drapes and desktop nova :)

Comment: Thanks, but these change wallpaper on an interval. I want it time-based, so it changes at a certain clock time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Afaik the sunrise script below does that(?) it changes the images based on your server time (when it is nighttime it shows an nightly background).

Answer (score 4):

DesktopNova  : [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/desktopnova)

[image]

> DesktopNova changes the desktop background image after an adjustable time. It can choose the images from single files and folders (with or without subfolders). An autostart feature is also implemented.

- [Website](https://sites.google.com/site/haliner/desktopnova)
- [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/desktopnova)

So you add your pictures, and then Check Change wallpaper in intervals.

And there is an [indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators/38011#38011) for this application.

Comment: Thank you man, I was looking for something like this for .... Since when does this goldnugget exist in the repository?

Comment: @dago: Anytime man, Yeah this an awesome application! and yeah it is in the repository !

Comment: @dago oh quite a while. It's one of those unknown gold nuggets in USC.

Comment: Yeah there is a punch of gold nuggets applications in the Software Center, But Reviews made them easy to discover :)

Comment: Thanks, but these change wallpaper on an interval. I want it time-based, so it changes at a certain clock time. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Actually this isn't so bad, the indicator lets me change it on demand. Thanks!

Comment: @nLinked: I don't think there is a tool that uses a time-based technique to change wallpapers. But I'd suggest the sunrise script below by Rinzwind.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Desktop Drapes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/drapes) [image: Install drapes]

Besides the wallpaper changers in USC (like Desktop Nova and Desktop Drapes) there is also a script called Sunrise that can do this and you can get it [here on deviantart](http://barid42.deviantart.com/art/A-Day-in-the-Life-204881196).

Instructions:

- Copy the file to a new directory.
- Extract the files.
- Inside a terminal, `cd` into the folder you created.
- Run `sh ./install`

It has an XML file with the images and in it also a timer (in seconds).

By default it uses the images shown on [this blog](http://expressubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/04/automatically-change-wallpaper.html).
Or course using a script is not as secure as using a package but it's very lightweight.